# Call-by-reference semantics for RPC

Tags: programming-languages, distributed-systems

Does call-by-reference semantics for remote procedure call (RPC) have a real use case?  Why does call-by-reference RPC exist?  Is it useful for anything?  Is there a scenario where call-by-value can't do the job?

In a simple sentence: Do we need to have a (call by reference)-able RPC protocol? if yes, Why?

---

Background: Call-by-reference can be implemented for RPC.  For instance, one implementation strategy is copy & restore: the value is copied from the client to the server when you make the call, and then copied back afterwards.  There are other ways to implement it as well.

Comment: I think this might be specific to the RPC implementation, in which case, it would be off-topic here.

Comment: I still think the question is conflating semantics with *implementation strategy*.  It's reasonable to ask whether there is a use case for a particular semantics, such as call by reference.  But I stand by my earlier comment that there are other ways to implement call by reference semantics in RPC without using copy & restore.  I've edited it into a form that I think makes more sense.  See if you agree.

Comment: @D.W. yes this does the job too; I don't have any interest on implementation techniques but I wanna know is there a scenario that we need to use call by reference and /or it has any benefit over call by value so we need to be able to implement it in RPC in any possible (and non-important) way or the existance of call by reference is just a peer to the traditional and non-rpc method of func/proc call in programming and doesn't have any special reason for existence? Thanks for putting time on this

Answer (score 2):

The *idea* is to be able to modify the argument. FORTRAN used call-by-reference always, Algol-60 used the (mathematically clean, but hard to implement and with surprising corner cases) call-by-name; Pascal distinguishes between call-by-value and call-by-reference ("gets the variable"). But call-by-reference has its surprises, introducing aliasing between variables. Thus Ada offers call-by-value-return too.

If caller and callee reside on different machines, the performance gain of not copying arguments in and out, just using a pointer, is lost. Even worse, doing call-by-reference is quite inefficient (need to copy back and forth each time something changes). If you are defining what to do, I'd just ditch call-by-reference, and fight users tooth and nail to keep it out.